# error: incompatible types: App cannot be converted to Configuration

Tags: android

My App.java is as follows:

```
package com.prodatingscript.demo;

import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;


public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

I get error: incompatible types: App cannot be converted to Configuration in the last line (Parse.initialize(this); whenever I try to build the project,

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: @Elletlar I am actually using Back4App, Their quickstart guide: https://github.com/back4app/android-quickstart-example